# Visual studio 2012 neither able to add database file (.mdf) nor create aspnetdb with Sql Server 2012 x64

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, database-connection, sql-server-2012

I'm using VS Pro 2012 and SQl Server 2012 64 bit developer edition.

Here is a quick view of my SQl configuration and the errors when taking ASP.NET configuration in VS 2012 and when adding a new database.mdf file. Notice that I can connect to SQL server database created with aspnet_regsql tool from Server browser window.

I've tried most of the answers for similar questions I found.

[image: VS2012 error creating database - SQL server 2012]

> There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused
> by an invalid server name or credentials, or by insufficient
> permission. It can also be caused by the role manager feature not
> being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page where
> you can choose a new data store.
>
> The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Unable to
> connect to SQL Server database.

Please help me solve the problem with VS 2012. I've tried it with both win7 & win8 installations, but all in vain.

The connection string uses default `Data Source=.;` and I can connect to default instance `.` from SQL server Management Studio.

Comment: looks like a connection problem. since the DB engine/server located in localhost just try with `proper host name of localserver` and see if you can connect. I mean, if your localhost `hostname` is `winserver123` (example) then try connecting with `winserver123`

Comment: I've tried with my `machine-name`, default instance `.`, `(localhost)` and `machine-name\MSSQLSERVER`. But giving those in `Tools > Options > Database Tools > Data Connections > SQL Server Instance Name` didn't solve my problem.

Comment: NO, since it's default instance don't punch the instance name just try with machinename ... your server will automatically figure out the instance name.

Comment: Again, what type of connection you have set up ... is it windows authentication or sql server? see that you are login with proper name.

Comment: I tried with both Windows Authentication & SQL Authentication with user 'sa', still its not connecting. It is connecting only in Server explorer and SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: How come you can try both? authentication setup will be configured while you install sql. Not sure how you are doing it.

Comment: While setup, I chose mixed authentication mode, so both modes are enabled.

Comment: last one, while installing did you added your local account to the windows authentication? If possible, try doing a full install again just with windows authentication and your local account. See if that helps.

Comment: Yes, both my account and Administrator were added to the list. As I mentioned already, I can connect with SQL Server Management Studio.